# Is there a way to trigger full screen in cypress?

Tags: cypress

I'm using cypress and I would like to trigger the F11 button in order to enable the full screen mode.
This code doesn't work:

```
cy.get('body')
 .trigger('keydown', { keyCode: 122 , release: false, force: true })
 .trigger('keyup')
```

Comment: It doesn't but thank you anyway. It doesn't help me because I don't need the full screen mode in the cypress environment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can use a combination of `cy.viewport` ([docs here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/viewport#Examples) and `window.screen` ([docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/screen)). To force Cypress to enter fullscreen mode. This is not equivalent to actually pressing F11, but that command is a browser-specific command, so I'm guessing you are more concerned about window behavior and not browser behavior.

```js
cy.get('body');
cy.viewport(window.screen.width, window.screen.height);
```